# Collect multi inputs with to one validation on yii framework

Tags: php, javascript, yii, validation

I'm using Yii framework and I have form with 3 inputs for phone number. I split it for this format (XXX-XXX-XXXX)
every split by minus is input.
I want to validate it after user change/pass all 3 fields and give one error message if it is not valid.
I want to save it with the same order and split it back to the same format.

This is example of my code.

```
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'phone'); ?>

<?php echo $form->textField($model,'phone[0]'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'phone[1]'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'phone[2]'); ?>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can validate inputs at the controller and add error if needed:

```
// ...
$validator = new CRegularExpressionValidator;
$validator->pattern = '/^[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{3}/';
if ( !$validator->validate( $model->phone[0] ) ) // Do this for all of your phone fields!
{
    // add error if not added yet: $model->addError( ... );
}
if ( $model->validate( null, false ) ) // notice the 2nd argument!
{
    // ...
}
```

Or you can define your own validator at the model class with pretty the same code (this is the better option I believe).

Comment: But i must join the 3 fields first. How can I do that?

Comment: You will have to do this validation check for each of your fields. You don't have to join values (don't know what are your fields: array of field or each field have it's own name). If your phone fields are array, create validator in the model and loop in the array. If phone fields have different names(e.g. they are not as array), define validation at the controller and add error only once(rise flag or something).

Comment: Its make me an error.
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
if ( $validator->validate( $model->attributes ) ) // Do this for all of your fields!

Can you describe full code for how to combine the inputs?

Comment: Validating of the _all_ of the model's attributes doesn't make sense. You should validate _only_ fields that need to pass this particular validation. For example: `if ( !$validator->validate( ($model->phone[0] ) )` and so on. As I point out in the answer, this also could be done with custom validator at the model. You can see examples in the Yii's documentation.